# How can I remove a badge which I accidentally earn?

Tags: discussion, badges

I was just surfing questions, and I came across a question. But accidentally I clicked on downvote for that question. I immediately changed my downvote, but still, I earned a Critics badge. Can I rollback badges I earned?

As it is been tagged as a duplicate of a question I will clarify a bit more. How can we give up a badge by our own choice?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: @Cai just curious so I posted

Comment: Answer is simple: you can't do that. Just let it be, no harm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is **NO**.

I can explain with an example. The [Cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/4/cleanup) badge is awarded for rollback of a edit. Even if the post is deleted also the user still can hold the badge.

So once the badge awarded it can't rollback except the **Tag Badges**.